# Jenkins console output has an error with log permissions

Tags: jenkins

My jenkins setup is not overly complicated, there are just a bit over 200 jobs; the problem I'm having is as follows:

1. The jobs folder is mounted on NFS drive;
2. Some of the jobs are creating log file fine, but then it is loosing permissions completely (it becomes 000), resulting in an error on the console regarding log file permissions:

[image: Jenkins screenshot with error]

I've checked and rechecked permissions on the folder and all the jobs, but nothing is there stands out that could explain what's the cause of the problem. It's not an issue on its own, but some of the jobs are quite important, and without manually fixing permissions, they can't be debugged.

Any hints would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it's more than likely that your version control (e.g Perforce/SVN) sets log files to read only permissions when synced.

An easy work around to this problem is to add an "Execute Windows Batch Command" build step where you cd into the directory containing your log file and change it's permissions.

Use the commands: 
cd 
attrib -r

This will alter the permissions of your log file and allow your jobs to write to the file. I'm sure there's other ways of dealing with this issue but this is a pretty quick and easy way.